# Difference between the 2 similar postgres statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my product install script, I see 2 similar postgres statement

```
grant select on all tables in schema rejected_events to REM_USER_READONLY

alter default privileges in schema rejected_events grant select on tables to REM_USER_READONLY
```

Since the 2 statements are executed one after the another, i think there must be a reason for their existence.

Can anyone please confirm if these two are same or different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query

```
grant select on all tables in schema rejected_events to REM_USER_READONLY
```

gives select permissions to the existing tables.

The other query

```
alter default privileges in schema rejected_events grant select on tables to REM_USER_READONLY
```

gives select permissions to the new tables that could be created in the future.